# LimeTabularExplainer TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python

I am trying to use LIME package for explaining predictive models. See error while running the following code:

```
# Create the LIME Explainer
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(X_train_undersample feature_names = feature_names,class_names=['0','1'], kernel_width=3)
```

Error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If you x_train is a DataFrame, try passing it like:

```
x_train_undersample.as_matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your X_train_undersample is DataFrame stype. It will be fine if you change the DataFrame stype into an array stype (eg. a float64 array).